# Can't write my table to PDF using WriteHTML in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mpdf

Im trying to print my table to PDF using the mpdf library in CodeIgniter, but I can't get the data
I'm using into the mpdf library. When I echo my $table, I can see/preview it, but when I write it to PDF, no data appears. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance..

```
          $mpdf = new mPDF('',    // mode - default ''
                     '',    // format - A4, for example, default ''
                     7,     // font size - default 0
                    'arial',    // default font family
                    10,    // margin_left
                    10,    // margin right
                      5,     // margin top
                    5,    // margin bottom
                    2,     // margin header
                     2,     // margin footer1
                      'L');  // L - landscape, P - portrait

  $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');   

  $mpdf->WriteHTML($table);       
  $mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: try `$mpdf->debug = true;` to see what happen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i got this message when "Output has already been sent from the script - PDF file generation aborted."..

Answer (score 0):

Look for any whitespaces before `<?php` and after `?>` (if exists) and remove them.

If that not work, post more php code please.

Comment: i can already view it to php, thank for the help everyone.
my problem is when my report is greater than one page, it will cause an error.. but if one page only, it is correct. can anyone help me.?

Comment: you can't output more than one pdf at a time.